# Using a variable outside of it's scope

Tags: swift, scope

I wish to access a variable outside of it's scope. (A snippet of the relevant code is posted). Within the @IBAction ,the sphereNode.runAction(moveUp) is not recognised.

I cannot simply declare sphereNode global as it is dependant upon the sphereGeometry declaration.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Added our first shape = sphere
    let sphereGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 1.0)
    let sphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: sphereGeometry)
    sphereNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0)
    sphereGeometry.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = UIColor.redColor()
    sphereGeometry.firstMaterial!.specular.contents = UIColor.whiteColor()
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)
}

@IBAction func animateButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let moveUp = SCNAction.moveByX(0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0, duration: 1.0)
    sphereNode.runAction(moveUp)
}
```

}`

Beginner programmer so please simple explanations are appreciated - thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need here is an instance variable.

Variables cannot be used outside their scope (and eventually you'll learn this is a really great thing).  But we can expand our variable's scope:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {
    var sphereNode: SNNode?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Added our first shape = sphere
        let sphereGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 1.0)
        self.sphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: sphereGeometry)
        self.sphereNode?.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0)
        sphereGeometry.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = UIColor.redColor()
        sphereGeometry.firstMaterial!.specular.contents = UIColor.whiteColor()
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)
    }

    @IBAction func animateButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        let moveUp = SCNAction.moveByX(0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0, duration: 1.0)
        self.sphereNode?.runAction(moveUp)
    }
}
```